How to execute thousands of requests using both Concurrency and Parallelism using playwright with python?
I am currently on a crossroad whether to use AsyncIo or AsyncIO and multiprocessing. I stumbled upon an external python package called aiomultiprocesswhich simplifies the use of both AsyncIO and multiprocessing together.
I decided to test out 2 sets of codes, each of them is tasked to run a hundred requests asynchronously and print out the website title for each request. After finishing all of the requests, a time will be printed out indicating how long the requests took.
AsyncIO
import asyncio
import time
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Browser

async def worker(browser: Browser, i: int):
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/")
    print(await page.title())
    await context.close()


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(channel="chrome")
        await asyncio.wait(
            [asyncio.create_task(worker(browser, i)) for i in range(100)],
            return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED,
        )
        await browser.close()

start = time.perf_counter()
asyncio.run(main())
end = time.perf_counter()
print(end - start)

Time taken: 8.336619800000335 seconds
Aiomultiprocesses
async def run(playwright, url):
    chromium = playwright.chromium # or "firefox" or "webkit".
    browser = await chromium.launch(channel="chrome")
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await page.goto(url)
   
    print(await page.title())
    await browser.close()

async def mains(url):
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        return await run(playwright,url)

async def main():
    urls = ["https://www.google.com/" for i in range(100)]
    async with Pool() as pool:
        async for result in pool.map(mains, urls):
            None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Python 3.7
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start,end="")

Time taken: 17.115715199999613 seconds
I am unsure if I am doing this correctly, however these are my questions.

Am I doing it correctly? If not, how can I make it go better and go faster?
Should I just stick with AsyncIo?
If I were to scale up to thousands of requests, how should I do it with playwright or any other scraping libraries?


if you were to scale up to thousands of request and performance and safe code is of concern you should not use python.
